# How to give an array as feature value to Scikit learn regression algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data, supervised-learning

If I have a feature whose value is a array of strings, how can that be fed to any regression algorithm in scikit learn?

For example if my features are like - `[45, 56, ['abc', 'vfg'], 'EF', 567]`
I know I'll need to transform the categorical features to numeric ones, but will it work if I send 3rd feature column as an array? or I will need to encode / explode that one into many columns?

Comment: are all the arrays of the same length? also what is their entropy? if you have only a few types, maybe you could label encode them

Comment: No, all arrays won't be of same length. will that affect?
Also even if I manage to make them of same length and label encode them, my question is whether can I pass in as is to scikit learn regression algo's fit methods?